# How to make filename of file uploaded with getClientOriginalName make safe?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filesystem

In https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-uploads I read as file custom file uploading :

```
However, keep in mind that the getClientOriginalName and getClientOriginalExtension methods are considered unsafe, 
as the file name and extension may be tampered with by a malicious user. For this reason, you should typically prefer the 
hashName and extension methods to get a name and an extension for the given file upload:
```

I do not like using of hashName I would prefer original name, making it safe.
I wonder what how file name can be unsafe ? I know that say login/username can be used to bypass login procedure.
But File name ? If it can be unsafe, how to modify ot to make safe ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what if two users upload a file with the same file name ?

Comment: Even though [this post](https://lessthan12ms.com/dont-trust-files-users-upload-to-your-server.html) doesn't cover both file name and extension, at least it can give you an idea of the kind of things that can happen. Also, generating a file name you reduce significantly the chances of storing files with same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things i had to implement to kinda avoid this security hole since nothing is safe nowadays.

1- Use a custom approach to name files, you can add a GUID for instance to the client file name.

2-Add  right after <form method="POST `"enctype=”multipart/form-data"`

3-for the validation you can add

```
'image' =>  'file|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif|max:1024',
```

Comment: I am pondering the same problem.  I am using ```$this->photo->store('photos');``` to store an image, and it creates a unique name (guid).  but i think i want to store the original name in a table, so I am trying ```$name = htmlspecialchars($this->photo->getClientOriginalName());``` hoping the html() funciton will take out anyting dangerous.  I'm not sure that is enough.  as u know laravel docs recommend using $file->hashName(), but what good is the hash name?  you cannot get the original name of the file from the hashname I don't think; hashName() will return a different name for the same file

Comment: a good practice is to store it as hash+datetime.now you can even tokenize that concatenation to simplify any query